# Merge 3 functions in jQuery

Tags: javascript, jquery, function, merge

These functions works perfectly, but I be sure that there is a smarter way than this:

```
$(window).scroll(function(){
  $('#header').css({
    'left': $(this).scrollLeft() + (($(window).width() - $("#header").width()) / 2)
  });
});

$(window).resize(function(){
  $('#header').css({
    'left': $(this).scrollLeft() + (($(window).width() - $("#header").width()) / 2)
  });
});

$(function(){
  $('#header').css({
    'left': $(this).scrollLeft() + (($(window).width() - $("#header").width()) / 2) 
  });
});
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can give a name to your function :

```
$(window).on('scroll resize', something).trigger('resize');

function something(){
  $('#header').css({
    'left': $(this).scrollLeft() + (($(window).width() - $("#header").width()) / 2)
  });
}
```

Comment: I don't understand where you're including it being called for `$(function(){});`...

Comment: @Ian It is true that i forgot to wrap all that in a DOM ready handler, but since OP accepted this answer, i suppose the code is at the bottom of the page. His DOM ready in the original code was probably just to trigger the event once on load. `.trigger()` do the same.

Answer (score 1):

Encase it in a function and call it in 3 places.

```
$(window).scroll(function () {
    alignHeader()
});

$(window).resize(function () {
    alignHeader()
});

$(function () {
    alignHeader();
});

function alignHeader() {
    $('#header').css({
        'left': $(this).scrollLeft() + (($(window).width() - $("#header").width()) / 2)
    });
}
```

You can also try this approach

```
$(window).on('resize scroll', alignHeader)

$(function () {
    alignHeader();
});

function alignHeader() {
    $('#header').css({
        'left': $(this).scrollLeft() + (($(window).width() - $("#header").width()) / 2)
    });
}
```